# auto show seeker bar in media player framework

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm using Player Framework in my windows store app

http://playerframework.codeplex.com/

I want to use it only for audio files (no vide). Now I want that when user starts the track the bar with seeker, pause/play, volume is visible. I achived that when you move mouse over it and it will be shown it won't vanish. But I need to show it on start. How can i do that ?

It looks like this in my app

```
<mmppf:MediaPlayer Name="TrackPlayer" Width="400" Height="50" AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia" AutoHideBehavior="None" IsDurationVisible="True" AutoHide="False" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set **IsInteractive="True"**:

```xml
<mmppf:MediaPlayer Name="TrackPlayer" Width="400" Height="50" AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia" IsInteractive="True" IsDurationVisible="True" AutoHide="False"  />
```